# HTTP Status 404 - Not Found in Servlet crud

Tags: java, servlets

i am creating a simple crud system in Java Servlet. I am beginner of  Servlet.I filled the form and clicked submit button and got the error - HTTP Status 404 - Not Found. I have attached the screen shot image below along with the code.

[image]

**folder structure**

[image]

**Form**

```
<form method = post action = "employee/employee.java">
           <table class="table table-borederd">
        <tr>
        <td>Enter Employee ID:</td>
                <td ><input class="form-control" type = "text" name = "txtEmpId"/></br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Enter Employee FirstName:</td>
        <td ><input class="form-control" type = "text" name = "txtFName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Enter Employee LastName:</td>
        <td ><input class="form-control" type = "text" name = "txtLName"/></td>
        </tr>
        <td><input type = "submit" value = "submit"/></td>
    </form>
```

**employee.java**

```
public class employee extends HttpServlet 
{  
    Connection con;
    int row;
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse rsp) throws IOException, ServletException
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/empp","root","");
                System.out.println("Connection Established");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry...........");
            }
            rsp.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = rsp.getWriter();
            String empId = req.getParameter("txtEmpId");
            String empFName = req.getParameter("txtFName");
            String empLName = req.getParameter("txtLName");
            try
            {
            PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("insert into record (id,fname,lname)  Values(?,?,?)");
            stat.setString(1,empId);
            stat.setString(2,empFName);
            stat.setString(3,empLName);
            row = stat.executeUpdate();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<font color = 'red'>Sucessfully registered!</font>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("<h2>");
            out.println(row);
            out.println("</h2>");
            out.println("</body>");
        }  

}
```

Comment: You do not post to a java file `<form method = post action = "employee/employee.java">` - read a tutorial on posting to a servlet

Comment: so how to post it sir

Comment: Post it to your servlet name - see `web.xml`

Comment: Please read about `@WebServlet("/servletname")`.

Comment: how to write the url sir <form method = post action = "employee/employee.java"> here i attached the folder structure screen shot